# How to Replace multiple pixels with each numbers in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two np-array and one list like this.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
y = np.ones((3,3))
idx = [[1,1],[2,2]]
```

```
x
>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
y
>>> array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

I would like to get z array like this.

```
z
>>> array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 5., 1.],
       [1., 1., 9.]])
```

Like above z array, i would like to replace index index of `y` in `idx` with index index of `x` in `idx` by ***not*** using `for-loop`.

If I use for loop, I can do it like this.

```
for i in range(len(idx)): 
    y[idx[i][0]][idx[i][1]] = x[idx[i][0]][idx[i][1]]
```

Actually, this is easy example, but I have bigger array, so if I use for-loop, this takes much time.

HOW TO DO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop, it defeats one of the reasons to use NumPy -- vectorized operations.

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
y = np.ones((3,3))

# Rows and columns to filter.
idx = np.array([[1,1],[2,2]]).T

# Copying desired elements of x to y.
y[tuple(idx)] = x[tuple(idx)]
```

Taking the transpose of index as NumPy expects you to pass a tuple of row indices and column indices `(row_idx, col_idx)`, which in your case would be `([1, 1], [2, 2])`.

Comment: Thanks you.
It's so clever method, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Let numpy do the looping for you:

```
idx = np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
y[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]] = x[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]]
print(y)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 5. 1.]
 [1. 1. 9.]]
```

Comment: Thanks.
This is very clever method, I think.